# Very weird behaviour with my C++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've been debugging this for a long time now - but I have no clue what the issue is.

I get a `name` from the console (via `std::cin`) and then proceed to create a new `Player` object with it. Then I pass the new object to the `Gameboard` to be added to a `std::vector<J>` where `J` is part of a template. Here's the code:

**main.cpp**

```
Gameboard<Tile,Player,5,5> board = Gameboard<Tile,Player,5,5>();
std::string name;

std::cout << "Enter a name: "
std::cin >> name;
board.setPlayer(Player(name));
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Enter a name: "
std::cin >> name;
board.setPlayer(Player(name));
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Enter a name: "
std::cin >> name;
board.setPlayer(Player(name));
```

**gameboard.h**

```
template<class T, class J, const int X, const int Y>
class Gameboard {
    std::vector<J> players;
public:
    void setPlayer(J player);
};

template<class T, class J, const int X, const int Y>
void Gameboard<T,J,X,Y>::setPlayer(J p) {        
    ////// DEBUG CODE //////
    std::cout << p.getName() << std::endl;
    players.push_back(p);
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << players.at(i).getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**player.h/player.cpp**

```
class Player {
    std::string name;
public:
    Player(std::string _name);
    std::string getName();
};

Player::Player(std::string _name) {
    name = _name;
}

std::string Player::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

I think I've tracked my problem down to the code marked `DEBUG CODE`. Using the above code, and entering the names `Bob`, `Joe`, and `Tim`, I would get the following output:

```
Enter a name: bob
bob

Enter a name: joe
joe


Enter a name: tim
tim



[exit]
```

So somehow, when I add the player to the vector, it becomes corrupted or something similar. The object is valid right before insertion because I echo out the name. The vector is also growing in size because it's printing blank lines equal to the number of players added.

What is going on?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://gist.github.com/sharth/4e2da25f45b0889b6830

Comment: Also, note that you have some missing semicolons in your `main()`.

Comment: Can you post everything in one file so we can easily try to reproduce? The code looks correct though...

Comment: My guess is that at some point in your real code, you pass the `GameBoard` by value.

Comment: Could you post the code for the Player class? There is probably some issue with the way you are copying the player (i.e. while inserting into the vector). Looking at how your copy constructor for Player class is would help.

Comment: @BillLynch it shouldn't matter if he's using `std::string`, as the copy ctor of the latter should kick in, right?

Comment: @vsoftco I'm assuming the code that calls set player is in a function that has the gameboard passed by value.

Comment: @BillLynch The link you have in your first comment, that piece of code just works fine for me. what is it, I am confused here

Comment: Don't retype code.  Copy and paste actual code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: @BillLynch, I checked but that's not the case. Everything is happening in `main()`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, I wanted to but there's MUCH more code. And none of it has anything to do with the issue. I'll add some more to the post though.

Comment: @Rush, you were right! I had put in a definition for a copy constructor but not finished the implementation. I feel like a total idiot. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks everyone else.

Comment: Retype it.  Then paste it into a file, compile it, and **ensure the problem still happens**.  Retyping what you think what causes the problem then posting it is worse than useless: if you knew what was important to your problem, you could solve it yourself and would not need to post it.  By reducing, then testing, you can ensure you did not leave the cause out.

Comment: Given that you are using the STL anyway may I suggest a one-liner instead of a bulky for loop: `copy(players.begin(),players.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,",")); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a copy constructor where you are not copying the name. So when you push_back on the vector, a Player object with empty name gets pushed on the vector. 
Implement the copy constructor properly and it should work

Comment: Or let the compiler implement the copy constructor ;)

Comment: true that. Leaving it to the compiler in most cases is just fine

Comment: as long you're not messing around with plain old pointers/dynamic allocation

Comment: @BenVoigt, I have a `std::map` as another member. I figured implementing the copy constructor myself would make sure that they get fresh copies.

Comment: @vsoftco: Sure, follow the Rule of Five.  But also follow the rule of "one allocation, one object to manage it".

Comment: @maxmackie: The default copy constructor will call the copy constructor of each member.  `std::map` has a copy constructor with a reasonable implementation, and probably one that runs far faster than inserting all the elements into a blank new `map` object.